# »Verschieden von« vs »unterschiedlich von«

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

> Hochdeutsch ist unterschiedlich vom Schwyzerdütsch.
>
> Hochdeutsch ist verschieden vom Schwyzerdütsch.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Wörter »unterschiedlich von« und »verschieden von«  und in welchem Zusammenhang werden sie verwendet?

Comment: Beide Sätze sind nicht besonders idiomatisch, eher noch der zweite. In _vom_ steckt ein Artikel, also sollte dann auch _Hochdeutsch_ einen bekommen, sonst _von_. _unterschiedlich von_ ist insgesamt eher ungebräuchlich, eher _X wird unterschieden von Y_, _X und Y werden unterschieden_, _X unterscheidet sich von Y_, _X und Y sind unterschiedlich / verschieden_, _X und Y sind unterschiedlich / verschieden_, _X ist anders / etwas anderes als Y_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um den Kern der Frage zu beantworten: Beide Worte können als Synonyme verwendet werden.

Menschen sind unterschiedlich oder verschieden.
Dinge sind unterschiedlich oder verschieden.

Verschieden kann allerdings auch gestorben bedeuten, möglicherweise kann man auf der Grundlage eine Entscheidung für oder gegen eine Verwendung treffen.

Die genannten Beispiele sind allerdings wie von Crissov richtig dargestellt so falsche Verwendungen.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache!

Comment: Stimmt nicht ganz, da gibt es feine Unterschiede. Siehe hier: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-verschieden-unterschiedlich-a-327300.html

Comment: Dem Zwiebelfisch kann ich nicht ganz folgen :) "verschiedene Fingerabdrücke" soll hier einfach nur mehrere Fingerabdrücke bedeuten. Die Verwendung von verschiedene ist hier m.E. unangebracht. Davon abgesehen kann ein Mensch sehrwohl mehrere unterschiedliche Fingerabdrücke hinterlassen. Ähnlich ist es bei den Interessen: mannigfaltige oder verschiedene? Das mag gesprochen üblich sein aber verschieden ist kein Synonym für "viel".

Comment: Ziehe das zurück: Offenbar IST verschieden in der Bedeutung von einiges / manches verwendbar. Und unterschiedlich auch für mannigfaltig. Ich bleibe aber dabei, dass man sie problemlos synonym verwenden kann ohne dass es je einem Deutschlehrer aufstoßen wird, und das war ja die Frage.

Answer (score 6):

Es gibt doch feine Unterschiede: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-verschieden-unterschiedlich-a-327300.html

**Excerpt from the source above:**

> Gelegentlich aber kann die Verwendung von "verschieden" zu
>   Missverständnissen führen. Die Aussage "Sie hatten verschiedene
>   Interessen" kann in zwei Richtungen gedeutet werden, nämlich sowohl
>   als "Sie hatten diverse Interessen (z.B. reiten, malen, kochen)" wie
>   auch als "Sie hatten nicht dieselben Interessen". Um in solchen Fällen
>   klar zu machen, dass "verschieden" nach der ersten Lesart aufgefasst
>   werden soll, bedient man sich gerne der Steigerung: "Sie hatten die
>   verschiedensten Interessen."
>
> Ein weiteres Beispiel für den Unterschied zwischen "verschieden" und
>   "unterschiedlich": Wenn die Polizei nach einem Einbruch am Tatort
>   verschiedene Fingerabdrücke findet, kann sie nicht sofort daraus
>   schließen, ob ein oder mehrere Täter am Werk gewesen sind. Erst wenn
>   sich herausstellt, dass es sich um unterschiedliche Fingerabdrücke
>   handelt, ist klar, dass mindestens zwei Täter ihre Finger im Spiel
>   hatten. Ein einzelner Mensch kann durchaus verschiedene (das heißt:
>   diverse, mehrere) Fingerabdrücke hinterlassen, aber nicht
>   unterschiedliche.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'll edit it..

Answer (score 5):

Unterschiedlich kann auch verschieden sein, verschieden ist aber nicht zwingend unterschiedlich. Ist so wie bei different und various im Englischen.

Es ist ein schöner, feiner Unterschied, eine Nuance dazwischen.

Beispiel:
"Franz hatte ich den letzten Jahren verschiedene Partnerinnen."
Bedeutung: Er hatte nicht nur eine, es waren mehrere. (Ob es immer derselbe Typ war, oder unterschiedliche Typen bleibt offen und liegt nicht in der Absicht der Aussage.)

"Franz hatte ich den letzten Jahren unterschiedliche Partnerinnen."
Bedeutung: Er scheint nicht auf einen Typ festgelegt zu sein. Die eine war etwa streng und groß, die andere lustig und klein, eine weitere war geheimnisvoll, schweigsam und mittelgroß.

Noch deutlicher:
"In der Firma XY sind momentan verschiedene Stellen zu besetzen."
Bedeutung: Möglicherweise handelt es sich um mehrere Stellen mit der identischen Positionsbezeichnung, z. B. "Sachbearbeitung Buchhaltung".

Hingegen: "In der Firma XY sind momentan unterschiedliche Stellen zu besetzen."
Bedeutung: Hier sind es ausdrücklich unterschiedliche Stellen, z. B. in der Buchhaltung, im Verkauf und im Lager.